# Why does this JavaScript array return undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, hashmap, associative-array

Can someone explain when I run this file using node why one value is returning as undefined and the other is not included in the list.

- 0 Cam
- 1 Doug
- 2 Caleb
- 3 David
- 4 Kelli
- 5 Aparna
- 0 Cam
- 1 Doug
- 2 undefined
- 3 David

  ```
  var queue = {};

  queue[0] = 'Cam';
  queue[1] = 'Doug';
  queue[2] = 'Caleb';
  queue[3] = 'David';
  queue[4] = 'Kelli';
  queue[5] = 'Aparna';

  var sorted_keys = Object.keys(queue).sort();

  for (var key in sorted_keys) {
  console.log(key + " " + queue[key]);
  }

  for (var key in sorted_keys) {
  if (key == 2 || key == 4) { // trying to mock disable accounts and remove
      delete queue[key];
   }
  }

  sorted_keys = Object.keys(queue).sort();

  for (var key in sorted_keys) {
      console.log(key + " " + queue[key]);
  }
  ```

Comment: `Array.prototype.sort` is in-place.

Comment: You should stop using `for ... in` to iterate through JavaScript arrays.

Comment: use an array instead of an object for ordered collections, or feel free to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @pointy: care to explain why?

Comment: @defau1t JavaScript is different than PHP - `for ... in` is not even guaranteed by the spec to present the property names in any particular order! It also causes optimization problems for V8.

Comment: @Pointy what would be a better way than using for in

Comment: @CalebKing3 `for ... in` is for iterating over object property names. For arrays, use either a plain `for` loop with a numeric index, or else use the `.forEach()` method on the Array prototype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main issue is that you're iterating `sorted_keys` which is an array of keys and you're trying to use the index value from the array to index into the `queue` object, but that's the array index, not the key into the `queue` object.  You need to get the actual value from the array, not the index from the array because that's where the key into the `queue` object is.

You also shouldn't be iterating arrays at all with `for/in`, though that isn't what is actually causing the problem.

If you change your last iteration to this, you will see what you expect:

```
for (i = 0; i < sorted_keys.length; i++) {
    key = sorted_keys[i];
    console.log(key + " " + queue[key]);
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5dPsR/